# Do exist programs to verify demostrations in logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, math-software

I am a universitary teacher of logic and I´m interested to design an create a program to verify demostrations about propositional and predicate logic to my students, but I want to know if programs to do that really exist and how works that. If you know about some program, or how works the code, you will helpme a lot. Thanks.

Comment: [Fitch system](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/glossary/fitch_system.html)

Comment: [Has anyone thought about creating a formal proof wiki with verifier?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41214/has-anyone-thought-about-creating-a-formal-proof-wiki-with-verifier)

Comment: A google search for "automated theorem proving" and "proof assistant" will get you much better information than the answers posted to date.

Comment: I'm voting to close because your question is essentially about career advice. If you are teaching logic at university level you should not need to ask this question.

Comment: You might also google "software to teach the basic methods of proof"

Comment: If you want not a full proof assistant, but a tool to teach the basis of formal reasoning, you will be interested in edukera.com . There is support for proof in traditional style or using natural deduction trees.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of proof assistants out there, e.g. [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/), [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php). If you're new to this stuff, I think you'll like Lean, because its syntax is fairly intuitive and there are online tutorials on the website.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've [read](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-proof-assistants-such-as-Coq-or-Isabelle-and-logic-programming-systems-such-as-Prolog-or-MiniKanren), theorem provers are "typed variants of the $\lambda$ calculus". On the other hand there are logic languages such as Prolog. Prolog is a programming language with "roots in first order logic". So depending on the focus of your course(s), one or the other might be better (program focused on theorem proving vs a language focused on first order logic).

As an example of Prolog, this statement demonstrates implication where the antecedent is true: "known(Q) :- known(P), known(implies(P, Q))"

Comment: Your reading seems to be a bit limited in this context. The OP is asking about tools that verify logical proofs. Prolog does not do that (but one can write Prolog programs that do).

Comment: No, IMO the OP is asking "to verify demostrations[sic] about propositional and predicate logic" and "design an[sic] create a program". As my example showed if can "verify a demonstration". And more importantly it can "design and create a program". Ultimately neither you nor I know the larger context of what he'll be doing with whatever tool he uses. For example if his course doesn't use the $\lambda$ calculus or similar, it may be too much to ask his students to learn it.

Comment: I think you need to learn a lot more about this subject. Your statement "theorem provers are typed variants of the $\lambda$-calculus is nonsense". My first comment was trying to give you a gentle hint, but that obviously wasn't sufficient.

Comment: I quoted this blog: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-proof-assistants-such-as-Coq-or-Isabelle-and-logic-programming-systems-such-as-Prolog-or-MiniKanren. In addition the Introduction to Lean says that it uses the Calculus of Inductive Constructions formal language. What happens if the questioner doesn't want to teach his students CIC? Also what about his stated desire to "create a program"?  Finally, what harm does it do to point the asker to logic languages?

Comment: @Xpw: what good does it do to write nonsense like "theorem provers are typed variants of $\lambda$-calculus"? Why do you consider it to be within your right to pontificate in this way on topics that you know very little about?

Comment: I didn't pontificate, I quoted. I live in the US, so I don't think there's any doubt I have the right. Why aren't you addressing any of my questions in these comments?

Comment: @Xpw: you are pontificating to the OP about the design of their course. God bless the USA, but I don't think your US citizenship qualifies you to provide advice  based on nonsense and expect it to be taken seriously.

Comment: I don't think "pontificate" means what you think it means. And you still haven't answered any of my questions. You seem to have a closed mind on this subject and not wanting to engage in a dialog. Rather, you appear to want to lecture.

Comment: "Pontificate" means to play the part of a pontiff, i.e., to make definitive statements about matters of belief. (Apologies, if you think that someone who lives the other side of the Atlantic is stepping out of line by giving you,  a US resident, advice on the English language.) You need to work on your nonsensical statement about theorem provers and the $\lambda$-calculus if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57516/discussion-between-p-and-rob-arthan).

Comment: Merriam Webster defines it as "to speak or express opinions in a pompous or dogmatic way". My statement "From what I've read, theorem provers are "typed variants of the λ calculus" isn't  even an opinion - it is a statement of fact. I did read that. The other statement I made that is vaguely close to an opinion was "So depending on the focus of your course(s), one or the other might be better" That certainly isn't  dogmatic. If you don't like the statement you visit the link and argue with the author. **You still haven't answered my questions**

Comment: "Theorem proves are typed variants of the $\lambda$-calculus" is a false statement, which you state dogmatically with no justification other than "from what I have read".

Comment: Speaking of predicate logic... The statement I made is true. It is what I read.  If I say, the "I read in the Daily Mail that Bob murdered Alice to keep his proclivities secret", that statement is true whether Bob murdered Alice or whether Bob had proclivities he wanted to keep secret. **YOU STILL HAVEN'T ANSWERED MY QUESTIONS**

Comment: Please don't shout. It is down to the OP (who has probably died of boredom by now) to answer your questions about the relevance of your digressions to his or her interests.

Comment: My questions were not to the OP. There were to you. BTW, wouldn't need to shout if you'd listen.